# Number of cores on FreeBSD

Tags: scripting, freebsd, cpu

What would the equivalent of Debian's `nproc` be in FreeBSD? I'm trying to include this in a bash script variable so if it could just print out the number of cores that would be fantastic.

Comment: Do you want the equivalent of 1) nproc's default behaviour, e.g. to print the number of available processing units for the current process, or 2) nproc's behaviour when it's called with `nproc --all`: to print all the available processing units, e.g. processors, cores and threads as in @carleson's answer?

Answer (score 10):

```
# sysctl -n hw.ncpu
2

# alias nproc='sysctl -n hw.ncpu'
# nproc
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Whis would do it !

```
# sysctl -a | egrep -i 'hw.ncpu'
```

Or with some extra info:

```
# sysctl -a | egrep -i 'hw.machine|hw.model|hw.ncpu'
```

Comment: From [nproc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nproc.1.html): "[`nproc`] prints the number of processing units available for the current process, which may be less than the number of online processors". `sysctl hw.ncpu` prints the number of all available processing units, so I'd say that your answer is not completely correct. However, `nproc --all` still prints all the available processing units, which makes your answer partially correct.

Comment: Yes, @Risto you´re right. But from the question we really can´t tell what Dominique exactly wanted ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's very true.

Comment: You can shorten this - to simply: sysctl -an hw.ncpu

Comment: Can be even shorter: sysctl -n hw.ncpu

Comment: You should really do `sysctl hw.ncpu` instead of listing all and throwing away the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just number of cores in variable:

```
NPROC=`sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'`
```